# Supervisor not approving submission because of coauthor he didn't approve of

Tags: phd, advisor, authorship, collaboration

Okay I'm pretty desperate here.

I'm a PhD student. I had a cosupervisor (Prof Y) that my supervisor (and head of center, Prof X) removed (without consulting me) from my project and assigned (again without consulting me) another cosupervisor (Prof Z). The assigning of cosupervisors to a PhD project at my university happens with a form that both the new cosupervisor and the student need to sign, which I did not, and thus my supervisor (Prof X) thinks he's (Prof Z) my cosupervisor, but formally he isn't.

I have a publication ready that he (Prof X) needs to approve before I submit. His major issue with the paper is the fact that as a coauthor I have added my ex-cosupervisor (Prof Y), who indeed has scientific contribution. I received an email telling me that he has not been informed that I was working with my ex-cosupervisor (Prof Y), that this is not normal practice and that he (Prof X) won't approve the submission because of this.

Does he have the right to do this? Where is the academic freedom in policing who I collaborate with to such an extreme extent?

Please let me know your thoughts. I feel like I'm losing it.

UPDATE: I've contacted the vice-dean. He's going to look into the situation as I forwarded everything to him and tell me his opinions. He was shocked that my supervisor/HoC needs to also approve submissions.

UPDATE 2: Vice-dean has encouraged change of supervisors. He will support me throughout the process and will handle all economic issues himself. I'm arming myself with all the legal matters now. I'm making a meeting with prof X to politely explain that this is happening.

UPDATE 3: I changed supervisors. I lived. I'm so much happier. Thanks for the encouragement.

Comment: Should 'supervisor' be replaced with 'cosupervisor' in "and thus my supervisor thinks he's my cosupervisor, but formally he isn't." If so, then please edit to clarify.

Comment: If your supervisor is not a co-author, then you might not need their permission to submit for publication. It depends on your university's internal guidelines. That said, submitting without permission seems likely to create further problems between you and your supervisor.

Comment: It shouldn't, because my supervisor is also head of center. He has removed my ex cosupervisor and assigned (verbally) a new cosupervisor for me, but this has not been formalised.

Comment: Also supervisor IS an author. His complaint is that my ex-cosupervisor is an author as well.

Comment: Is this submission essential for you to get your PhD? In other words, are you at risk of losing a publication only (minor) or both publication and PhD (major)?

Comment: Since your supervisor is a co-author, you cannot submit without their permission. Perhaps you can ask your ex-cosupervisor to speak to your supervisor directly? Alternatively, perhaps you can speak to a senior member of your center and ask for their help in finding a resolution?

Comment: Dmytry, this one is sadly very essential. :(

Comment: A senior member would be the vice-dean. I'm trying to find other solutions before I go there.

Comment: Senior members, other than the vice-dean, will suffice. E.g., anyone with a high academic rank (including the previous head of center). Also, any long-standing, well-respected member of the center will suffice.

Comment: There's no such person unfortunately. This guy started this center so there's no previous. Well-respected members are also not co-authors on this one so I don't think they'd be inclined to help. But I am on first name basis with the vice dean, so I could speak with him. I was hoping for an option that doesn't involve another party.

Comment: Before you go to the vice-dean, what about meeting with your ex-cosupervisor who might have first-hand insight in whatever political game might be happening that caused them to be removed as your supervisor in the first place.

Comment: **Don’t walk. Run.**

Comment: I know exactly what removed my excosupervisor. It was the fact that I contributed to a paper that she was first author on, that he was not coauthoring on. He got very angry over the fact that his (technically she was cosupervising me) PhD student collaborated with someone "behind his back."

Comment: I found this really difficult to follow who's who - could you perhaps add fake names, or "Prof X", "Dr Y" etc, to help clarify?

Comment: Edited now to include your suggestion.

Answer (score 28):

To learn at submission stage who else is coauthor on a paper is unusual, indeed. So to some extent, your supervisor being annoyed is understandable. To block the submission of the paper is a rather extreme reaction though. Could there be some history between supervisor and ex-cosupervisor that you are unaware of? (e.g. your supervisor suspecting the ex-cosupervisor of data manipulation, etc.)

My suggestion would be to apologize to your supervisor for the lapse in communication, and to ask about his reason for blocking the publication. Provided that this is indeed the case, it could help pointing out that the contribution of your ex-cosupervisor happened prior to him being removed as your cosupervisor.

If this approach fails, then the right moment to speak to the vice-dean has arrived.

Comment: The contribution didn't happen before my ex cosupervisor was made an ex. It happened after. But I was under the impression that I am allowed to seek help from whomever in the center. I'll try to do what you have said.

Comment: Is removing the contribution by your supervisor an option?

Comment: I contacted the vice dean, he suggested the same thing. He's going to call me later to give me his 2c.

Comment: @little.toblerone, I recommend considering other options first. Removing an author will (?almost?) always cause tension.

Comment: I've considered removng my ex-cuspervisor (Prof Y), but in truth, she has a tremendous scientific contribution and I cannot in my right mind do it. Even though she has agreed. I think I should bite the bullet, remove him, and ask him for the travel money if it's accepted.

Comment: @Fanciful I doubt that there is a solution which will make everyone happy. If your ex-supervisor understands the situation and accepts be removed from the list of authors, that seems like the least-unhappiness solution, both in the short run and in the long run. To ease your conscience, maybe your supervisor would accept that you acknowledged your ex-supervisor (profusely) in the body of the paper? Politics happen...

Answer (score 14):

Since your [supervisor is a co-author](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/98572/supervisor-not-approving-submission-because-of-coauthor-he-didnt-approve-of#comment255174_98572), you cannot submit without their permission.

**Seeking a strong ally to help find a resolution**. In the first instance, I recommend seeking the support of your ex-cosupervisor. They might well be unable or unwilling to help, given that your supervisor is head of center. In that case, I recommend seeking a powerful member of the center. E.g., anyone with a high academic rank or any long-standing, well-respected member of the center. Such a powerful person is interested in the success of the center (rather than what sounds like a quarrel between your supervisor and ex-cosupervisor). That success is determined in part by your success and the success of your fellow PhD students. Hence, powerful people should be willing to help. (Even when [they aren't a co-author](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/98572/supervisor-not-approving-submission-because-of-coauthor-he-didnt-approve-of#comment255181_98572).)

Comment: Right. Which in my situation translates to "Speak to the vice-dean. He's the one who cares about this." Thank you.

Comment: I'm inclined to disagree that the vice-dean is the only person who will care about this. But, I do not know your circumstances, so I might well be wrong.

Comment: Also technically he has 0 contributions to the paper other than saying "I think this is a good idea" one time. Twice I've requested a meeting to discuss publications and he has simply not expressed interest to discuss this under the excuse that he is extremely busy. He accuses me of working behind his back unless I add him as an author.

Comment: @Fanciful, on that basis, your supervisor doesn't seem to be a co-author.

Comment: he isn't. But I dare not open quarrel with him on that basis. He practically removed Prof Y from cosupervisor because she had published a paper that I contributed to without his name on it. I fear that if I tell him he doesn't deserve to be there, that it will make it even worse. He's already strongly insinuated my insubordination due to the fact I've collaborated with this person.

Comment: As @JeffE hinted, you might want to find a new supervisor.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm looking into that. The university has an incredibly complex of applications, and a hearing process to change supervisors, so there's no way to do this quietly. It also takes time, and no one will give me an extension to the PhD to compensate for that time. I've tried to avoid this option. :(

Comment: You mightn't need an extension. E.g., you can continue working without interacting with your current supervisor. Albeit, the process of changing supervisor will of course take some of your time.

Comment: I can, but I also need to make a case against him. Currently, I'm on stress-based sick leave because I cannot work in the same building as him. This conflict here is the last of too many condescending remarks and issues. But anyway. Thanks for listening I suppose. My current course of action is see what the vice dean says about it.

Comment: If this supervisor is causing you to be ill as a result of their actions then that seems like reasonable grounds to initiate a change (though I'm not in a position to say for sure). It may be neither quiet nor quick, however as much as that may cause problems on balance it could be better than developing health problems trying to power through in a grim situation.

It depends on what constitutes appropriate cause to build a "case" against them.

Comment: The penalty for using the word “insubordination” in front of a student should be immediate loss of tenure; alas, you’ll have to settle for firing them as your advisor. Get out now. Find a new supervisor ASAP. Do not ask for your old advisor’s blessing, and do not apologize for leaving them. Walk away from the paper if you have to. Pursue other remedies only after you are in a stable situation yourself. Your mental health is more important that a single paper or even your degree.

Comment: JeffE, I have to personally thank you for all this encouragement. Your phrase "Don't walk, run." is what made me really understand that it's alright to quit with him as supervisor, especially when I have a new one who'd really love to have me. I am making an application and am taking care of all aspects. The vice-dean has helped me take care of the economic aspects. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, narcissistic, power seeking people are also present in academia.

My wife had a similar supervisor during her PhD, who could mostly offer scathing criticism, but not much help. He didn't let her publish articles or her thesis in a timely manner, because he was unsatisfied with her academic writing, but wouldn't help her much in learning that.

The solution was, as @user2768 suggested, to seek powerful allies. They kind of forced her supervisor (who was the head of department) to sign her PhD thesis.

I posted an answer instead of a reply, because reputation counts here apparently, just as in academia :)

Comment: Who were these powerful allies in the situation with your wife?

Comment: Well, mostly senior researchers from the same department, and if I remember well, a person of higher position she was in good terms with. Eventually, all of the department knew about the case.

Answer (score 2):

> I had a cosupervisor (Prof Y) that my supervisor (and head of center, Prof X) removed (without consulting me) from my project and assigned (again without consulting me) another cosupervisor (Prof Z)

I would tell X that he is the reason for the confusion because he removed Y without consulting you. Such behavior can always cause such unpredictable consequences and indicates personal problems.

Otherwise, what is the contribution of your supervisor? Maybe you can delete his part and swap the supervisor. I don't know him, but for me it looks like, I would not continue to work with such a person. The reason I would try to remove the part of the supervisor is that he is the blocking element.

**Edit (after it is clear that X has no contribution):**

Just tell Y that X removed him without your approval, and (if possible) that you want to change supervisor because X abused his position. If Y  agrees to be supervisor, *tell Y to set X in CC or to inform him*, so it is not behind his back (which is the most important step). Then delete X from publication. Additionally, if X makes trouble tell him to make a list of his contribution which allow him authorship.
I was working for some time as PostDoc and in my opinion it is a complete waste of time to spend more then the absolute minimum in discussions with such people.

Comment: He does not have a contribution so I could remove X. My fear is he'll accuse me of "working behind his back" as he has done on another occasion before.

Comment: What are the consequences of his accusation that you are “working behind his back” (whatever that means)?

Comment: @JeffE I'm not in the scientific community, but I think if the asker wants to continue research in this field, this person could potentially hinder his/her career in the future.

Comment: He has not stated explicit consequences. General dissatisfaction with me, I suppose. This can easily imply inviting malicious behaviour such as not approving the paper (like now), refusing to provide funding for travel to the conference, give poor comments despite my true performance, anything. He's insinuating at a breach of loyalty and trust. The only possible repercussion is a change in relationship. From kind(ish) to hostile.

Comment: Time to change supervisor then. Otherwise you will have just a lot more trouble in future.

Comment: I'm already preparing my application. It took me a long time to make this decision because of the same fear that he will start being malicious and sabotage my entire career. But I can't stand for unethical behaviour. I am a researcher in training and there are many things I don't know (but want to learn). But I do know that removing authors who have scientific contribution just because he's HoC is wrong. We clearly have a difference in values.

Comment: The worst what he can do is writing a bad recommendation letter and I already saw such students from time to time showing up with letters indicating such issues. Some institute leaders take that with humor. However, far more important than this is to get papers. Just try to find a way to get your stuff published, in best case without him.

Comment: If I switch supervisors, doesn't that imply that the new supervisor will give me the recommendation?

Comment: Yes. Just sometimes people ask all kind of former supervisors for letters because usually you need more than one :/ But this should not be an issue for you.